# Continuous maps from an absolute Galois group

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, algebraic-curves

Let $\xi$ be a continuous homomorphism from an absolute Galois group $G_{\bar{K}/K}$ (Krull topology) to a finite abelian group $M$(discrete topology), where $K$ is a number field and $\bar{K}$ is its algebraic closure.

Let $S$ be a finite set of the places of $K$.
We know $\xi_v$ for any places $v\not\in S$.

Then is $\xi$ determined?

I am asking this after reading the book Silverman's AEC,p334,line 10.

Comment: Key "word": **Chebotarev Density Theorem**.

Comment: Thank you very much. I understood it after rereading the theorem in Neukirch's ANT.